# Nested ListView is not working in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Nested list view is not working, I have a list which contains another list in it. To show it in View I am using Nested listview; But the code is not working,and i am not able to identify on where it went wrong... Below is my code

**Main Page**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView  x:Name="outerListview"   ItemsSource="{Binding lst}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell x:Name="outerListviewCell">
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <ContentView>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell x:Name="InnerListviewCell">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding stockQty}"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public MainPageViewModel()
{
    lst = new ObservableCollection<A>()
    {
        new A()
        {
            ItemName="Item1", ItemList=new ObservableCollection<ItemDetails>()
                {
                    new ItemDetails() { stockQty="2"},
                    new ItemDetails(){ stockQty="3"}
                }
        },
        new A()
        {
            ItemName="Item2", ItemList=new ObservableCollection<ItemDetails>()
                {
                    new ItemDetails() { stockQty="3"},
                    new ItemDetails(){ stockQty="4"}
                }
         }
     };
}
```

**Model ( Class A and Class Itemdetails)**

```
class A:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public A()
    {
        ItemName = string.Empty;
        ItemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemDetails>();
    }
    private string _ItemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return _ItemName; }
        set { _ItemName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ItemDetails> _itemlist;
    public ObservableCollection<ItemDetails> ItemList
    {
        get { return _itemlist; }
        set { _itemlist = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
class ItemDetails:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _stockQty;
    public string stockQty
    {
        get { return _stockQty; }
        set { _stockQty = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

When I Run the above code I am getting below output in screen

```
2
3
```

What is expected actually is

```
Item1
2
3
Item2
3
4
```

What is wrong in above code? could anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Nesting `Listview` inside another `Listview` is not a good idea and it is not a supported on Xamarin.Forms.

`ListView` is very "sensitive" and it can easialy cause problems with scrolling and of course there are problems with poor performance of your app.

So I strongly recommend you to rethink about your layout and take a look at Grouping with `ListView` more about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Grouping), maybe you can achieve what you want with Grouping.

Comment: Almir, Thanks for your reply. Actually I cannot change the layout and have to use Nested ListView.  I will be receiving list of object and each object contains list of items; I need to display all  and I cannot Group it.

Comment: To use a grouping don't implies to change layout. You can have the same layout with the correct approach, that is grouped listview as @AlmirVuk suggested

Answer (score 1):

After checking your code , I found something need to modify in your code.

1. In order to show the `ItemName` , you should wrap Label inside StackLayout .
2. In order to get Uneven Row, you should set `listview.HasUnevenRows = true`.

Modify your code as below:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView  x:Name="outerListview" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding lst}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell x:Name="outerListviewCell">
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <ContentView>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" RowHeight="20">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell x:Name="InnerListviewCell">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding stockQty}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely wrong. You must use one ListView with IsGroupingEnabled set to True.
Follow instuctions here to make it work correct: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/