# How to bind list inside ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have one ListView on my page having `ItemSource` as `List<AssetModel>` as shown below:

```
public class AssetModel
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<TaskDetail> TaskDetailList { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDetail
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind `TaskDetail` list in my parent list?

**Desired Layout:**

[image]

Comment: It depends on how you wanna show the data. Can you share your desired presentation layout?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza please check image i uploaded

Comment: It seems you have a nested listview. So you gotta set your nested listview's ItemSource as "TaskDetailList".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems like a classic grouping listview use case. [James Montemagno wrote an article about this kind of need that should help you a lot](https://montemagno.com/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping/).

In summary, the grouping feature expects an object of type 'List of List' (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>`), where each 'master item' is a list of 'detail item'.

To make it easy, you can use the class provided at the above mentioned article:

```
public class Grouping<K, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public K Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(K key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then, the list property you must change its type to, for example, this:

```
ObservableCollection<Grouping<AssetModel, TaskDetail>> AssetsList { get; set; } = 
    new ObservableCollection<Grouping<AssetModel, TaskDetail>>();
```

*This `AssetsList` is what you should bind to the `ItemsSource` of `ListView`*

To fill this property, you'll need, for example, do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var asset = new AssetModel();
    asset.AssetId = new Guid().ToString();
    asset.Description = $"Asset { i + 1} ";
    asset.TaskDetailList = new List<TaskDetail>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        asset.TaskDetailList.Add(new TaskDetail() { Description = $"Detail { (i + 1) } - { (j + 1) }" });

    var group = new Grouping<AssetModel, TaskDetail>(asset, asset.TaskDetailList);

    AssetsList.Add(group);
}
```

Then in your XAML you define your ListView Grouping properties:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AssetsList}" 
          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          SeparatorColor="Transparent"
          IsGroupingEnabled="True">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="AssetId"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text={Binding Key.AssetId}/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="Description"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text={Binding Key.Description}/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text={Binding Description}/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: bravo.. thank you so much for your valuable time to explain in depth.helped me lot.thanks again

Comment: @diego what if we have one more level of nested listview. I meant a listview in item templates.

Comment: @AbhinavRastogi I don't believe that to nest listview is a good idea. [Other agree with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47484052/8093394). It's discouraged mainly because of [issues with scroll events handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6211286/8093394), the same to [`ListView` inside a `ScrollView`(_see the Note_)](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView/#Remarks). Maybe worths for you to search/create a custom view that handles inner collections with only one scroll handler.