# Listview scroll issue when inside scrollview in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is a prototype of the design : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMDRA.png
Im not able to have the listView scroll if it's inside the scrollview.Is there anyway i can go about while having the scroll view for the Mainlayout enabled as well as the scroll for the listView which is inside another layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ListView is not working in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483402/nested-listview-is-not-working-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 2):

> Application developers should not nest one ScrollView within another.
>   Additionally, they should refrain from nesting them other elements
>   that can scroll, such as WebView.

Source: official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView?view=xamarin-forms#remarks).

Nested ScrollViews are disaster just don't do that.
Which control will get scrolled on a user interaction? It will totally ruin the UX, performance and etc. You have to rethink your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Like @EvZ suggests you shouldn't have a Listview which already has a Scrollview inside a Scrollview but unfortunately we might end up in this situations.

You can use this custom renderer for Android to make all your listview work inside scrollviews.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ListView), typeof(ListViewScrollRenderer))]

namespace Glu.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class ListViewScrollRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var listView = this.Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
                listView.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use nested scrollview, instead what you can do is have buttons instead of listviews and on click of that show listview as a different controller as popup.